# Image page border

Tags: html, css

I need to make a simple website by using html and CSS. What I have to do is: I need to take an image and make it a page-border.

So I can't show you guys what I have done until here. Because I did not know exactly where to start. But if I correctly understand. I have to put the picture in the html code. Then design it in the CSS file. But how and which codes?

```
<p><img src="images/logo.gif" alt="Head First Lounge" /></p>
```

But in CSS, I don't have that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is `border-image` property.

```
div {
    border:5px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(http://www.kswholesaletile.com/images/kswt-theme/diamond-tile-432x432.jpg) 10 10 round;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cc6aQ/)

Just make sure you also use prefixed properties to support older browsers i.e `-moz` or `-webkit`

Comment: yeah exactly.I want to make a border for all of the page. so not only a paragraph of a header.

Comment: @user3081200 than use `body` in the place of `div`

Comment: allright. and for example if i want to resize the border. like right section: 20 px and left: 15 px. what i have to write for that. border-size or something like that. btw thanks a lot.